# Homonymous function parameters and private variables

Tags: javascript, naming, naming-conventions

When having to format or transform some function parameters in JavaScript, I usually create homonymous private variables (private variables with the same names as the function parameters):

```
function myFunction(param) {
  var param = Math.floor(param);
  // More code referencing param many times here...
}
```

**Question:** is that considered bad practice? Is there any drawback I should be concerned about?

Comment: If the duplicate declaration is as obvious as in the example, I personally would consider it bad practise. However, in a long variable initialisation (maybe multiline var declaration) it can be OK if it would look odd otherwise.

Comment: @bergi Could you develop what you think is bad about it? Not saying it's not (good or bad), just trying to understand your rationale. I should have indicated that the modified param can be referenced multiple times in the function's code. If it was used only once, I would not create a variable for it obviously.

Comment: If you're accessing a primitive it's needless since you could just modify the parameter directly.  If you're accessing a reference that may be shared outside of this context it's bad practice since it's more likely to confuse someone at a glance that is reading your code afterward or yourself in a year if you change your style between now and then and forget about your previous quirks.

Comment: It's not inherently bad. The fact there are people voting to close this question means there is no ultimate reason in favour or against this. I'd say use it if it feels right to you.

Comment: @mahn Thanks for the heads up. That helps. That being said, where should questions about best practices (which are usually fairly subjective) be asked on StackExchange? Or is there no place for it?

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi sadly folks here don't like questions that can generate debate, and that's usually the case with questions about best practices that don't have a definite answer. *Some* of these kind of questions could fit in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ depending on how you word them.

Comment: @mahn Got it! Thanks. I'm starting to grasp the ethos of the place. There are lots of subtleties, but it seems to be working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the var is ignored by the interpreter and this is not defining a second variable.  So you might as well save you the time to type 4 extra chars :)

same thing as doing:

```
var var1 = 2;
var var1 = 3;
```

Comment: I would say it even more strongly: since it doesn't **do** anything, it is incorrect. Being incorrect, it is not best practice. Don't write programs that pretend to do things that don't work!